# Azure graph explorer

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

I would like to try/test Azure AD user creation Graph API using Graph API explorer.

1. Is there is any restrictions that we can test this API thru application permission only not as signed in user?
2. If so, can I register the postman application in Azure AD and call user create graph API thru postman with application permission?
3. Does it require premium license to call http connector and Microsoft organisation account instead of Microsoft personal account?
4. Is this Graph API explorer can be used for signed in permission mode only?

I am bit confused. Could someone please suggest the best approach on this?

Comment: Your questions should probably be directed at Azure support, they are definitely not the type of question you're supposed to be submitting to StackOverflow. If you've tried something in code and it didn't work and you're wondering if it's your code, or the restrictions on the API, that might be a question to ask here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because these are questions about a specific commercial platform, while not about coding at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there is any restrictions that we can test this API thru
> application permission only not as signed in user?

Of course, you need to grant application permissions to the application in Azure AD, then use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain the token, and then call the api in postman.

> If so, can I register the postman application in Azure AD and call
> user create graph API thru postman with application permission?

Of course, I suggest you do the same.

> Does it require premium license to call http connector and Microsoft
> organisation account instead of Microsoft personal account?

Not needed.

> Is this Graph API explorer can be used for signed in permission mode
> only?

Yes, Graph explorer can only be used to authorize the user login mode, and it uses delegated permissions by default.

Comment: Excellent clarification, very helpful. Thanks.